# Placeholder image and error image is shown larger when the glide loads the image

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using **Glide Library** for loading images in my android application. Whenever the image is loaded the placeholder image is shown for a while then the original image is shown. Original image is **300x300**. I resize the placeholder online to **300x300** and place it in my **drawable** folder, but when the image is loaded the placeholder is shown larger as compared to the original image. How can i set the placeholder and error to occupy exactly the same **300x300** when it tries to load the image?

Comment: do you have an  `.override(300, 300)` in your glide call?  `Glide.with(context)
            .load("url")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.no_image)
            .override(300, 300)
            .into(imageView);`

Comment: Yes....I have 
Glide.with(MainGUI.this).load(getImageURL()).asBitmap().diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.NONE ).skipMemoryCache( true ).override(300,300).placeholder(R.drawable.small).error(R.drawable.small) .transform(new CenterCrop(MainGUI.this),new CustomCenterCrop(MainGUI.this)).into(_USERImage);

Comment: refer to this i think adding .dontAnimate() solve it https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/542

Comment: dontAnimate is not working for me. I just tried @LaryCiminera

Comment: mmmh i made some test apparently it does not resize placeholder indeed, only solution i found is to put 300px to height and width to target ImageView....

Comment: Yeah this way it works